# IPhone: how to draw a simple colored rectangle with interface builder?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I'd like to draw two different colored rectangles (yes I need two.. it's a long story) to use as background. Like a simple two tone background color. How would I do this? The only thing I saw that comes close is defining a 'view' with a background color. So maybe I could do two views or something in the background but this seems kind of heavy weight. Either that or just create an image. But I was wondering if you know of a way to create a simple rectangle with a background color via interface builder?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by heavy weight?

Comment: heavyweight meaning it has ability to handle events and to add controls to it. I just wanted a box. Apple should add some basic shapes to their IB. Microsoft and Adobe did this ages ago.

Answer (score 8):

I would either use two empty `UIView`s with different background colors, or a single `UIImageView` with an image with those two colors. I don't see anything wrong with either option, performance-wise.

Answer (score -5):

You may take `UIButton` for this purpose.Just drag and drop a Round Rect Button from Tools->Library->UIButton to your Interface Builder.Now Resize the shape of `UIButton` according to your requirement.Finally set an background image for the color and disable the user interaction.

Comment: This wastes resources and violates the Apple Human Interface Guidelines.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Why make it a button? A UIView would serve the same purpose without the UIButton subclassing.